# How to install libvirt in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, libvirt

How to install libvirt-java-0.4.9 in Eclipse Juno Service Release, I cant get it. Pleas help

Answer (score 1):

Libvirt is a Python library and you need to install it from source code or from packages and after this, you find it at /user/local/lib/python2.7/dist-package/libvirt,
go to window -> preference-> pydev ->interpreter-python librery an new folder and add the path 
libvirt will be setup in eclipse